# Directly assign UnsafePointer

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

Can somebody please explain to me what I'm missing here?

Given

```
let index: Int32 = 100
```

Why is this not okay:

```
// Use of extraneous '&'
let ptr = &index // Type inference?
```

Or even:

```
// Use of extraneous '&'
let ptr: UnsafePointer<Int32> = &index
```

But this is:

```
{
    func point(num: UnsafePointer<Int32>) -> UnsafePointer<Int32> {
        return num
    }
    let ptr = point(num: &index)
}
```

This would be the simple equivalent of this in C:

```
int index = 100;
int *ptr = &index;
```

Do I really have to define a function that literally takes the referenced value and passes back the very same reference?  Something feels wrong about it.  It seems like I'm missing something here, maybe even fundamental.

**How do I assign an UnsafePointer to the memory address of the type it is (Int32 in this case)???**

Thanks!

Edit:

Ultimately what I'm attempting to accomplish is, I need to write several various structures into a binary file.  The variable `index` would be a property of a structure.  The path I'm going down now involves a file `OutputStream`.  I don't mind receiving suggestions on this, but gets out of scope of the original question.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use case for this? It's possible you're looking for `withUnsafePointer(to:)`, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I will edit the original question to elaborate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the precise rationale, but presumably `let ptr = &index` isn't allowed because there's no guarantee that you can dereference `ptr` without invoking *undefined behaviour* (assuming `index` isn't a global or `static` stored variable – the only cases where Swift guarantees stable and unique pointer values).

Unlike other languages, Swift doesn't guarantee that a local variable will remain initialised until the end of the scope it's declared in – the optimiser is free to deinitialise it earlier. Allowing `let ptr = &index` would therefore make it far too easy to write unsound code.

It's worth noting that your example of:

```
func point(num: UnsafePointer<Int32>) -> UnsafePointer<Int32> {
    return num
}
let ptr = point(num: &index)
```

is also unsound. Attempting to dereference `ptr` from `let ptr = point(num: &index)` is undefined behaviour, as the inout-to-pointer argument conversion produces a temporary pointer only valid for the duration of the function call.

If you want a *scoped* temporary pointer to a value, you can use [`withUnsafePointer(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2431879-withunsafepointer) – for example:

```
func baz() {
  var foo = 5
  withUnsafePointer(to: &foo) { ptr in
    // use `ptr` here – do not escape it!
  }

  // In Swift 4.2 you can also use `withUnsafePointer(to:)` on let constants.
  let bar = 5
  withUnsafePointer(to: bar) { ptr in
    // use `ptr` here – do not escape it!
  }
}
```

Note that the pointer is only valid for the duration of the closure – attempting to escape it will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the unsound-ness of that function and explaining why it does not work.

Comment: I think `withUnsafePointer` will work for me.  This may seem like a silly question, but I have to wonder, is that closure executed synchronously?  That is, will the `foo` closure execute before `let bar = 5`?  I'll be copying the data within ptr into a file `OutputStream`, so the order of execution is important.

Comment: @BrandonMantzey Yes, the closure is executed immediately (it's passed as a non-escape function, so it's impossible to be executed asynchronously).

Comment: Aha!  The purpose of the `@escaping` keyword makes sense now.  Thanks!